# Получить список пользователей онлайн discord C#

Tags: api, discord

Как получить полный список пользователей канала discord, пробую по api, но мне возвращает список 100 пользователей оффлайн, хотя их в онлайн больше.
Использую следующие запросы
Получаю список ролей
[https://discord.com/api/v9//guilds/{Group_id}/roles](https://discord.com/api/v9//guilds/%7BGroup_id%7D/roles)
Потом перебираю их и отправляю запрос
https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/id_group/roles/id-role/member-ids

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Commands : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
  {        
    private readonly IDiscordClient _client;

    public Commands(DiscordSocketClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }        

    [Command("get online user")]
    public async Task listCommand()
    {
        List<string> userlist = new List<string>(); // лист в который будут записаны данные о пользователях

        ulong guildId = 854327355608818497; // переменная с айди сервера
        var guild = await _client.GetGuildAsync(guildId); // получение инфы о сервере
        var users = await guild.GetUsersAsync(); // вытаскивает данные о всех пользователях

        foreach (var user in users) // цикл записывает ник и айди онлайн пользователя в отдельный элемент списка
        {
            if (user.Status == UserStatus.Online)
            {
                userlist.Add(user.ToString());
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllLines("onlinelist.txt", userlist); // запись списка в файл
    }
  }
```

Можно убрать условие из цикла:

```
foreach (var user in users) // цикл записывает ник и айди всеех пользователей в отдельный элемент списка
{
   userlist.Add(user.ToString());
}
```

Тогда в файл будут записаны все пользователи сервера

Comment: спасибо, а библиотека какая именно?